# What do I use to make a Neck Ring?

Tags: spacesuits

I’ve been working on a homemade space suit, and I’ve been trying to figure out on what to use to make a neck ring. But so far I can’t really find anything, Does anyone know what I could use for the neck Ring?

Comment: Might be worth clarifying if you are attempting to make a costume piece where you want the highest possible look quality but no function, or if you are trying to make a functional suit that holds pressure but do not care how it looks? For costume purposes, Adam Savage previously of Mythbusters has a large number of youtube videos for tested on making and sourcing costume suit parts that will probably point to websites devoted to just this topic.

Comment: What's your budget?

Comment: Is the internal suit pressure equal to the external pressure? If this is true you don't need a gas tight neck ring, a ring without a O-ring seal will do. A gas tight ring capable of a pressure difference of about 0.25  bar will be much more difficult to design and manufacture. Much more precision will be needed.

Comment: The Apollo suits used machined aluminum. The neck ring on some model may be anodized for the red color.